Add path tag for http_server_requests metric in Kamon
I have a scala app that uses pekko internally with an http server that runs the pekko actors for each incoming request.
For monitoring I'm using Kamon. Here's the config in my sbt file:
val kamonVersion = "2.7.0"
lazy val kamon = Seq(
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-bundle" % kamonVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-prometheus" % kamonVersion
)

Kamon sends metrics to prometheus using the following config:
kamon.prometheus {
  start-embedded-http-server = true
  include-environment-tags = true

  embedded-server {
    hostname = 0.0.0.0
    port = 9096
  }
}

kamon.instrumentation.pekko.http {
  server.metrics {
    enabled = yes
  }
}

The prometheus metric I care about is called http_server_requests, one of the problems with it, is that it is missing a path tag. Meaning I can't separate the metric by endpoints. Also, the http_status_code tag is not specific and just states the first digit of each response: 2xx, 4xx, 5xx.
Is there any way to have custom tags for this metric in Kamon? I want to know if it is configurable.

Kamon community looks fairly small and its metrics are basically hardwired. You could log an issue to see if someone is interested in making the enhancements that you need. These metrics should be easy enough to track explicitly in your own code - especially if you have a manageable number of routes - possibly with https://github.com/prometheus/client_java

https://github.com/RustedBones/pekko-http-metrics looks like a lib that has plenty of good features.
